# Fuel pipe on 2014 Accord

Tags: honda, fuel-system, accord

Had an auto body shop replace rear quarter panel. Gas hose nozzle keeps getting stuck. Seems body shop cut off the top of the fuel pipe, then reinstalled by crimping tabs they somehow created to reconnect.

Weren't they suppose remove the fuel pipe, and re-install it with the new quarter panel?

Should I demand they install a new fuel pipe?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having an issue with anything a body shop has done, take it back to them. Almost every major body shop (ones that do warranty repair) in the US gives a lifetime warranty on their work (they'll continue doing this if they want to keep getting the warranty work). I don't know if you live in the States, but if you do, they need to take care of it. Just tell them you are not happy with the work. If they give you a hard time, call the insurance company which paid for the work. You should not have to deal with second rate work.